# Maintain video position across postback?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html5-video, postback

I was wondering if there was any way to keep a position in a video across postbacks in ASP.NET? I have a function on my page that after every button click the video gets reset to the start position. I am using the HTML5  tag and .MP4 video format. Thanks.

Comment: thank you google t=0 in your uri will do the trick: https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/#naming-time

Comment: @Mederic Sorry im still a bit unsure, do you mean form the tag like <video>
       <source src="file.mp4#t=0" />  
   </video>
Thanks.

Comment: on click to reset video yeah you would change url of file to contain #t=0 if i'm not mistaken

Comment: I think that resets the video to the start position of 0. Im looking to maintain the current position in the video after a user postbacks the page after using a completely separate control. So if the user is on the 11th second of a video and then clicks a dropdown which causes a postback, that the video then resumes to the 11th second after the postback. Thanks

Comment: Oh ok sorry i understood the opposite because you used "reset" haha my bad

Comment: No problem thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use AJAX. I would look into UpdatePanels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

This will allow you to do a partial postback that doesn't effect the whole page.